# Silverlight or WP7 image button

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, imagebutton

Can anyone tell me what differences between these two examples

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="....."/>
</Button>
```

and

```
<Button>
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="....."/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

They do same thing - creating a image button. But I'd like to know the difference between them. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one sets the `Image` as a `Button.Content`, the second sets it as a `Background`, so I'm pretty sure you still can place some text over it when you use the second solution.